# Get number of items in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using php to create a highscore database for my iPhone Application. However it will only show 100 highscores (that I set). How can I change this to get the count of all of the rows in the database?

Here is part of my code:

```
$table = "highscores";

// Initialization
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

// Error checking
if(!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect ' . mysql_error());
}

$type   = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : "global";
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : "0";
$count  = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : "100";
$sort   = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "score DESC";
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM DB_NAME ?
What kind of SQL do you use to get the highscore ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of records from a table, you can try following code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from table_name");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result['total'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM highscores` will give you the number of rows in the highscores table.  But you would also get all the rows, if that's what you want to do, by eliminating the `LIMIT` clause from your query.  SQL defaults to giving you all of the rows that match.

Comment: I am getting this error: Error retrieving scores You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM highscores' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article for [Getting MySQL Table Size with PHP](http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/getting-mysql-table-size-with-php/)

Hope that helps.